# iOS - Xcode Error: cannot attach to process due to System Integrity Protection

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, runtime-error

When I running an application shared extension from XCode run button and then trying to share files, XCode shows the below error frequently. Anyone have any idea whats causing it?

[image]

Error: "cannot attach to process due to System Integrity Protection"

Comment: Not a duplicate but also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708417/instruments-cant-attach-to-running-process-on-iphone/53272592#53272592 for Instruments issues.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

System Integrity Protection(SIP) aka rootless is a new security feature in OS X 10.11. By default it disables even the administrator to access/modify the root.  Follow [these steps](http://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html) to disable SIP:

> 1. Restart your Mac.
> 2. Before OS X starts up, hold down Command-R and keep it held down until you see an Apple icon and a progress bar. Release. This boots
>    you into Recovery.
> 3. From the Utilities menu, select Terminal.
> 4. At the prompt type exactly the following and then press Return:
>
>    ```
>     csrutil disable
>    ```
> 5. Terminal should display a message that SIP was disabled.
> 6. From the  menu, select *Restart*.
>
> You can re-enable SIP by following the above steps, but using `csrutil enable` instead.

Comment: I have disabled SIP but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Then I guess you would have to try restarting Xcode, OS X and then try disabling SIP or enable it first and then disable it again. If this too doesn't work then I have no idea.

Comment: Be aware of the security risks you're incurring on disabling SIP (System Integrity Protection): https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899

Answer (score 7):

In some cases, if you are trying to connect to a "system provided" executable (for example, Terminal.app) there is a workaround by making a copy of such executable.  The copy will be checked by SIP as "user installed" instead of "system provided".

For an example, see 
[*"Launching the Terminal app from Xcode on OS X with System Integrity Protection"*](http://laurencescotford.co.uk/?p=1312)

Comment: Unfortunately this trick doesn't seem to work anymore (macOS 10.14).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I also get this error on Xcode while trying to run an app on simulator. Usually I only run the app again, and at most I restart the simulator, and it solves the problem.

Be aware of the security risks you're incurring on disabling SIP (System Integrity Protection):
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899